# Application-defined or object-defined error (VBA - Visual Basic for Application)

Tags: excel, vba

So, here's the situation. I'm trying to "map" a column in a certain sheet (the one called Metrics) in way to pick values that are close to that in other sheet (the one called StaticData) and transform them into their equivalent in the column G, next to this one.

My problem is that I'm getting the error "Application-defined or object-defined error (VBA - Visual Basic for Application)" and I don't know why!

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim limit As Integer
limit = 9999

Dim position As Integer
position = 0

Dim differenceA As String
Dim N1 As Integer
Dim differenceB As String
Dim N2 As Integer

Dim ref As String
ref = ""


For i = 1 To Rows.Count

       If Not Cells(i, 11).Value = "-" Then
        
           For j = 2 To 37
            
                If IsNumeric(Sheets("Metrics").Cells(i, "K").Value) And IsNumeric(Sheets("StaticData").Cells(j, "H").Value) Then
            
                    differenceA = Sheets("Metrics").Cells(i, "K").Value
                    N1 = CInt(differenceA)
                    differenceB = Sheets("StaticData").Cells(j, "H").Value
                    N1 = CInt(differenceA)
                    
                    If Abs(N1 - N2) < limit Then
                   
                        limit = Abs(N1 - N2)
                        position = j
                
                    End If
              
                End If
            
            Next j
          
            limit = 9999
            Sheets("Metrics").Activate
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "K").Value = CStr(Sheets("StaticData").Cells(position, "G").Value)
  
        End If

    Next i
    
End Sub
```

The IDE tells me that my error is in the line:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "K").Value = CStr(Sheets("StaticData").Cells(position, "G").Value)
```

I have also tried with:

```
Sheets("Metrics").Cells(i, "K").Value = CStr(Sheets("StaticData").Cells(position, "G").Value)
```

But I kept getting the same error... And also tried without the cast to String but it's the same case

Thanks!

Regards.

Comment: This error might mean, that some of the VBA libraries are not installed in your Excel VBA panel. On top of that, your code is missing:
Dim i As Long, j As Long
at the very beginning I guess

Comment: Are you aware that you are trying to overwrite the numeric values in column `K` of `Metrics` with whatever 'is found' in column `G` of `StaticData` converted to a string? Usually, the result is written to another column ('destination column') than the 'lookup column' (`K`) in `Metrics` e.g. column `L` i.e. `ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "L").value = ...`. Please do clarify.

Comment: You will get that error if position = 0

Comment: The second `N1 = CInt(differenceA)` should probably be `N2 = CInt(differenceB)`

Answer (score 0):

### A VBA Lookup with a Twist or Two

- Loops through the cells of a column `K` in a worksheet (`Metrics`) and finds the cell in a column (`H`) of another worksheet (`StaticData`) containing the closest value to the value in the current cell of the first worksheet (`StaticData`). Replaces the value in the first worksheet (`Metrics`) with the value found in a column (`G`) of the other worksheet (`StaticData`), in the same row as the row of the cell (in column `H`) containing the closest value previously found in the other worksheet (`StaticData`).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Button1_Click()

    Const sfRow As Long = 2 ' Source First Row
    Const dfRow As Long = 2 ' Destination First Row
    Const DiffMax As Double = 1000000
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("StaticData")
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Metrics")
    Dim dlRow As Long: dlRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim slValue As Variant ' Source Lookup Value
    Dim sr As Long ' Source Row Counter
    Dim sRow As Long ' Source Row
    Dim dlValue As Variant ' Destination Lookup Value
    Dim dr As Long ' Destination Row Counter
    Dim DiffFinal As Double
    Dim DiffCurrent As Double
    For dr = dfRow To dlRow
        dlValue = dws.Cells(dr, "K").Value
        DiffFinal = DiffMax
        sRow = 0
        If IsNumeric(dlValue) Then
            For sr = sfRow To slRow
                slValue = sws.Cells(sr, "H").Value
                If IsNumeric(slValue) Then
                    DiffCurrent = Abs(dlValue - slValue)
                    If DiffCurrent < DiffFinal Then
                        DiffFinal = DiffCurrent
                        sRow = sr
                    End If
                End If
            Next sr
            If sRow > 0 Then
                ' Change the 'K' to write to another column.
                dws.Cells(dr, "K").Value = CStr(sws.Cells(sRow, "G").Value)
            'Else ' no numeric value in cells of Source Lookup Range
            End If
        'Else ' not a numeric value in Destination Lookup Cell
        End If

    Next dr
    
End Sub
```